# Nginx proxy_set_header Authorization Bearer

Tags: nginx, return, bearer-token

I want to redirect from one particular endpoint to another URL along with  Authorization Bearer Token

ex:

```
location ~* /api/(abc_.+)/policy/ {
  return 307 https://xyz.in/policy/;
}
```

I tried to add

```
proxy_set_header  Authorization $http_authorization;
proxy_pass_header Authorization;
```

&

```
proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $arg_token";
```

And entered the bearer token, but none of them worked.

getting this error `{"message": "Authorization token missing"}`

Comment: The `Authorization` header won't be resent by the browser with a redirect to another domain. It has nothing to do with the `proxy_set_header` directives. Proxying and redirecting are two completely different things. Maybe you want to proxy this request to the `xyz.in` instead of redirecting it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to make the token available after the reverse proxy part ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind https? If yes, maybe you can try

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```